# malloc fails and return NULL

Tags: c

this is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int sendMessage(uint8_t *pui8MsgData, int messageLength, uint32_t ui32ObjID)
{
  int total = 0;
  int bytesleft = messageLength;
  int n;
  int chunkSize;

  while (bytesleft)
  {
    chunkSize = bytesleft > sizeof(uint8_t)*8 ? sizeof(uint8_t)*8 : bytesleft;
    uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * chunkSize);
    if(buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        return 0;
    }
    memcpy(buffer, pui8MsgData, sizeof(uint8_t) * chunkSize);
    n = send(buffer, chunkSize, ui32ObjID);
    total += n;
    bytesleft -= n;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

but for some reason, the malloc always return NULL.. what could be wrong? or how to get the error which is returned by malloc?

Comment: shouldn't chunkSize be a `size_t` not an `int` - at the very least it shouldn't be signed as you'll never be allocating a negative amount of memory

Comment: `sizeof(uint8_t)` is `1`, it would make your code a lot more readable to avoid redundant sizeofs and casts.  `chunkSize = (bytesleft > 8 ? 8 : bytesleft); uint8_t *buffer = malloc(chunkSize);`

Comment: Use `perror` on malloc failure.

Comment: You have tagged this embedded. [Why are you using malloc for in the first place?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/171257/realloc-wasting-lots-of-space-in-my-mcu/171581#171581).

Comment: Do you even have malloc and c runtime available in your **embedded** environment?

Comment: Regardless of the wisdom of malloc() in embedded systems, here its use is probably entirely inappropriate in any environment.  Simply create an array of 8 bytes and reuse it for each chunk.  It need not be a different buffer for each send() unless send() buffers the chunks and free's them itself - which is the only way this code would make any level of sense.

Comment: Target, tool-chain, library?  These determine whether malloc() is supported, and how the heap is allocated and supported - you have provided no information on these.

Comment: If you only wanted to know why malloc() fails you should have posted a simpler code fragment exemplifying just that issue - this example has too many other unrelated flaws that will distract. All you will get now is why you need not use malloc at all and comments on the apparent memory leak - which is all good, but when you really do want to use malloc() you will still not have an answer.

Comment: `sizeof(uint8_t)` cannot be anything than `1`

Comment: I like the solution to the criticism of using malloc in embedded systems - remove the tag!  However the reason for failure is probably exactly because it is an embedded platform w/o support for malloc() or with no heap allocation.  We need _more_ information, not _less_!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to to tell you what is wrong here with 100% certainty; there's too little information.

However, the `malloc()` seems pointless, and you never `free()` it. This is a memory leak, which might explain why you run out of memory, causing `malloc()` to return `NULL`. Seems plausible to me.

Just pass the data directly to `send()`, no need to allocate a new buffer and copy data around.

Edit: also, you never update `pui8MsgData` so you're processing the first bytes of the message over and over.

So, to summarize, the loop should be something like:

```
while (bytesleft)
{
  const chunkSize = bytesLeft > 8 ? 8 : bytesLeft;
  const ssize_t n = send(ui32ObjID, pui8MsgData + total, chunkSize);
  if (n < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Send() failed\n");
    return 0;
  }
  total += n;
  bytesLeft -= n;
}
```

This fixes the problem by removing `malloc()`. I also swapped the arguments to `send()`, assuming ui32ObjID is a valid file descriptor.

Comment: This zero-copy solution is good so long as send() is not buffering the chunks and attempting to free them, which is the only way the original code would have made any sense (though not necessarily a good design).  That is we have to be certain that when send() returns it has finished with the chunk, and that it is not attempting to free() the chunk when it _has_ finished with it.

Comment: @Clifford I simply assumed that `send()` is the POSIX standard socket function, i.e. [`send(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send).

Comment: In the absence of other information, the answer is reasonable, but the parameters are not right for POSIX send().  My comment was a warning that while likely to be correct, it makes (reasonable) assumptions.  Note also that it is not however an answer to the question of why malloc() does not work - there is still too little information provided to determine that.

Answer (score 1):

You are using buffer as the first argument to send(). But the send() function expects a file descriptor, not some uint8_t * so send() will likely return -1. This results in an ever *increasing* value for bytesleft, and thus an infinite loop with infinite memory allocations, eventually returning NULL.